# Why aren't my localStorage inputs persistent across pages on my personal computer?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying out the HTML5 localStorage  method for saving data. As I understand it, localStorage should be persistent between pages within the same domain. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

However, for some reason, it appears my localStorage values aren't persisting between pages in the same directory on my computer. Is it not considered the same domain in this case? I'm a little lost.

Here's the code for the two documents in question:

**Document 1** (assuming jQuery has been included elsewhere in the document)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#settings").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        localStorage["display"] = $("input[name='display']:checked").val();;
        localStorage["message"] = $("#disp_message").val();
    });
});
</script>
<form id="settings">
    <h1>Display</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="display" id="message" value="message" />
    <label for="message">Replace with message:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="disp_message" size="60" value="Test content." /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="display" id="hide" value="hide" />
    <label for="hide">Hide entries</label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Document 2**

```
<html><body>
    <script>
    document.write(localStorage["message"]);
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write(localStorage["message"]);
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Just to clarify the code a touch, the idea is basically to later use this for a Google Chrome extension to hide certain content based on certain criteria. Document 1 would serve as the basis for the Options page, and Document 2 would be the basis for the actual extension script. But that's irrelevant for my question.

As a final clarification, I have tried all three ways of storing and accessing the localStorage variable, i.e.:
    localStorage["key"] = "value";
    localStorage.key = "value";
    localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're testing in Chrome, everything under `file://`, even folders in the same directory are considered separate domains, so the same origin policy is kicking in, and the `localStorage` is unique to each.

I don't have a test environment setup at the moment, but launching with the command line flag:
`--allow-file-access-from-files` *should* be what you're after.